# Missing Semicolon error on ReactJS Context even though there is no need for a semi-colon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I tried to use the context hook on React. After importing the context from '.App' and declared it using useContext it's showing a missing semicolon error on line 6 where there is no need for a semi-colon. The code to the error is given below.

````
import React,{useContext} from "react";
import RecipeIngredientEdit from "./RecipeIngredientEdit";
import {RecipeContext} from "./App"

export default function RecipeEdit({recipe}) {
const{ handleRecipeChange }= useContext {RecipeContext}
  return (
    <div className="recipe-edit">
      <div className="recipe-edit__remove-button-container">
        <button className="btn recipe-edit__remove-button">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div className="recipe-edit__details-grid"> ```
````

Comment: Does the 3rd line require a semi-colon?  i.e. ```import {RecipeContext} from "./App";```?

Comment: `const{ handleRecipeChange }= useContext {RecipeContext}` that looks funky - what do you think that does? hint: that would not be a single JS statement - ever

Comment: @ewong Updated it but still getting the same error.

Comment: because you concentrated on the wrong line - line 6 has the issue because it is not valid

Comment: @Bravo I have just started learning coding in ReactJS and the tutorial that I was following was showing these steps. Can you please help me out here??

Comment: perhaps you could link to the tutorial that suggests `const{ handleRecipeChange }= useContext {RecipeContext}` is somehow valid code ... I may be missing something, but it looks like hot garbage rather than valid code - for one thing, `useContext` is a function, isn't it? ... so why aren't you calling it?

Comment: function {handleRecipeChange} is called from the RecipeContext by Using useContext."According to the tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put braces before and after RecipeContext

This Line Should be Modified To

```
useContext {RecipeContext}
```

This Code.

```
useContext (RecipeContext)
```